# RavenDB time based query

Tags: performance, time, ravendb

I have a document structure JobData that stores time based data starting from time 0 to time t in Ticks. And usually the data is a document per second.

```
public class JobData
{
       long Ticks {get;set;}
       double JobValue {get;set;}
}
```

For simplicity I am showing only one parameter JobValue, but in reality it is a complex graph of data. My question is if given a given an input time in Ticks, what kind of query would be the best for finding the last JobData based on a given tick?

So if the database has a document at 1000 ticks and then the next one at 2000 ticks, and the user wants to find the state at 1500 ticks, he/she should get the JobData at 1000 ticks as the answer.

The query I am using now is:

```
var jobData = documentSession.Query<JobData>().Where(t => t.Ticks <= 1500).OrderByDescinding(t => t.Ticks).FirstOrDefault();
```

Is this the right and most efficient query? I have thousands of these JobData nodes and want to just get to the one that is the closest.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ahmad,
Yes, that is the way to go about it. And it would be very fast.