# Modelling location history in RavenDB (to get entities state at certain time)

Tags: data-modeling, ravendb

We have a collection with `ItemId`/`DateTime`/`Location` fields.

We are tracking `Items` and their `Locations` (like, Storage1 or Building2 or City3. etc.) in time, `Item` might change its `Location` several times per day, or may not change a `Location` for a week.

Now I want to know, where all my `Items` were at a certain point in time.
Basically, I want to get the latest entry for each `Item` with `DateTime < N`.

What is the best way to query/model that in RavenDB?

If it makes things simpler, it's ok to query by Date only (i.e. without time), but simple grouping on ItemId-Date will not work, since there might be no entries for a certain `Item` on certain date.

The question is similar to [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275012/ravendb-time-based-query), but there the goal is to get the latest data for a single item, while I want to get the 'latest' data for all items.

Comment: Per document, are you keeping just the latest "location" ? or a list of "locations" that have changed ? can you share your model ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with `simple grouping on ItemId-Date will not work, since there might be no entries for a certain Item on certain date.` 
Why can't you query everything where `Date < N`, and do a reduce on it where you only take the max date? Yes you will not have entries for documents which never had a `Location` at all, but this you could handle in your application.